# Bloc & Hydrated Bloc Conflictions

Tags: flutter, bloc, codemagic

Getting Error in Codemagic building builds in testing section.

> ```
> BlocDelegate' is not a subtype of type 'HydratedBlocDelegate' in type
> cast\n\nWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It's not codemagic problem. You are using felangels bloc library with a hydrate bloc. Make sure you call

```
BlocSupervisor.delegate = await HydratedBlocDelegate.build();
```

in your main function and you don't set any other blocsupervisors as in
https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc